# Como implementar el max y el min en jpa, para obtener la fecha maxima y minima?

Tags: java, oracle, primefaces, sql, jpa

Tengo el siguiente query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findRegistroAccesoByNuserid", query = "select myRegistroAcceso from RegistroAcceso myRegistroAcceso where myRegistroAcceso.nuserid = ?1 and TO_CHAR(myRegistroAcceso.fecRegistroEntrada, 'dd/MM/yyyy') =  ?2")
```

ue me regresa registros de acuerdo a una fecha y un id que le paso como parametro para que haga el filtrado, ese query se lo paso a una lista

```
listRegistroAcceso = registroAccesoService.findRegistroAccesoByNuserid(cvePersona, strFecha);

for (RegistroAcceso registroAcceso1 : listRegistroAcceso) {

    horaEntradaBiometrico = registroAcceso1.getFecRegistroEntrada();
    System.out.println("PRUEBA ENTRADA" +registroAcceso1.getFecRegistroEntrada());


}
```

hay un campo llamado fecRegistroEntrada, que quiero extraer de esa lista y me pinta lo siguiente en consola

```html
PRUEBA ENTRADA2015-03-06 14:05:50.0
PRUEBA ENTRADA2015-03-06 14:05:54.0
PRUEBA ENTRADA2015-03-06 14:05:58.0
```

Ahora solamente necesito pintar en una tabla el primer registro que pinta que es el "PRUEBA ENTRADA2015-03-06 14:05:50.0" y el ultimo "PRUEBA ENTRADA2015-03-06 14:05:58.0" o sea sacar el min y el max se podria decir, hice una variable llamada horaEntradaBiometrico, pero a la hora de pintarla en la tabla me toma el ultimo valor como le puedo hacer para obtener esas dos fechas y poder mostarlas?

hice este query usando el max y el min pero no funciona y no levanta la aplicacion, no se si este bien la sintaxis en jpa

```html
select myRegistroAcceso from RegistroAcceso myRegistroAcceso (select min(myRegistroAcceso.fecRegistroEntrada)from RegistroAcceso myRegistroAcceso 
               where myRegistroAcceso.nuserid = ?1 and TO_CHAR(myRegistroAcceso.fecRegistroEntrada, 'dd/MM/yyyy') =  ?2
               UNION select max(myRegistroAcceso.fecRegistroEntrada) from RegistroAcceso myRegistroAcceso 
               where myRegistroAcceso.nuserid = ?1 and TO_CHAR(myRegistroAcceso.fecRegistroEntrada, 'dd/MM/yyyy') =  ?2)
```

Asi tengo el service

```html
public List<Obejct[]> findRegistroAccesoBy(Integer cveUser, String fecha);
```

```html
@Override
    public List<Object[]> findRegistroAccesoBy(Integer cveUser, String fecha) {
        return new java.util.ArrayList<>(registroAccesoDAO.findRegistroAccesoBy(cveUser, fecha));
    }
```

y el DAO

```html
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public Set<Obect[]> findRegistroAccesoBy(Integer cveUser, String fecha) throws DataAccessException {
        Query query = createNamedQuery("findRegistroAccesoBy", -1, -1, cveUser, fecha);
        return new LinkedHashSet<Object[]>(query.getResultList());
    }
```

asi declare la lista

```
private List<Object[]> listFechas = new ArrayList<>();
```

y le pase el find

```
listFechas = registroAccesoService.findRegistroAccesoBy(cvePersona, strFecha);
```

EDIT

ya obtuve la fecha de la siguiente manera

```html
private List<RegistroAcceso> listRegistroAcceso2 = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Object[]> listFechas = new ArrayList<>();
private Date fechaMaxima;

//Obtiene la fecha maxima 
        listFechas = registroAccesoService.findRegistroAccesoBy(cvePersona, strFecha);

        Iterator it = listFechas.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Object[] line = (Object[]) it.next();
            RegistroAcceso eq = new RegistroAcceso();
            eq.setFecRegistroEntrada((Date) line[0]);

            listRegistroAcceso2.add(eq);
            fechaMaxima = listRegistroAcceso2.get(0).getFecRegistroEntrada();
            
                System.out.println("PRUEBA NUEVA LISTA" +fechaMaxima);
            }
```

y me pinta en consola esta fecha

PRUEBA NUEVA LISTA 2012-08-02 18:55:28.0

Ahora la pinto en mi tabla, en el campo ENTRADA

```html
<!--Tabla que muestra los detalles de las incidencias-->
<p:dataTable id="detalle" var="detalle" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.fechasIncidencias}" emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros." selectionMode="single" selection="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.fechaIncidencia}" rowKey="#{detalle.fecha}">

  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.seleccionaFecha}" update=":form:carDetail" oncomplete="PF('modalIntentos').show();" />
  <p:column headerText="FECHA" style="width: 100px;">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.fecha}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="ENTRADA" style="width: 100px;">
    <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.fechaMaxima}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>

  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="SALIDA" style="width: 100px;">
    <h:outputText>
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="INCIDENCIA">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.incidencia.incidencias.cveIdIncidencia} - #{detalle.incidencia.incidencias.concepto}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="ACCIÓN" style="width: 100px;">
    <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-search"></h:outputText>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

pero la pinta en todos los registros, y solo quiero que la pinte en la fecha que me devolvio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con esto pero sale null pointer

```
    public List<FechaIncidencia> crearFechaIncidencia(List<IncidenciaAnioMesDet> incidenciaAnioMesDet, List<RegistroAcceso> listRegistroAcceso2, int annio, int mes) {
    List<Date> fechas = crearFechas(annio, mes);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (Date fecha : fechas) {
        FechaIncidencia fechaIncidencia = new FechaIncidencia();
        fechaIncidencia.setFecha(fecha);
        calendar.setTime(fecha);
        for (IncidenciaAnioMesDet incidencia : incidenciaAnioMesDet) {
            if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == incidencia.getDia()) {
                fechaIncidencia.setIncidencia(incidencia);

                break;
            }
            for (RegistroAcceso registroAcceso1 : listRegistroAcceso2) {
                if (calendar.getTime() == registroAcceso1.getFecRegistroEntrada()) {
                    fechaIncidencia.setRegistroAcceso(registroAcceso1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        fechasIncidencias.add(fechaIncidencia);
        System.out.println("OTRA RUEBA" + fechasIncidencias.get(0).getRegistroAcceso().getFecRegistroEntrada());
    }
    return fechasIncidencias;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se ve un tanto extensa esa query, ¿no seria mas simple de esta forma?:

```
select min(r.fecRegistroEntrada), max(r.fecRegistroEntrada)
from RegistroAcceso r
where r.nuserid = ?1 and 
TO_CHAR(r.fecRegistroEntrada, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = ?2
```

Por cierto que el resultado seria un `Object[]` con 2 `Date`'s

---

Los obtendrias de este forma:

```
List<Object[]> fechas = em.createQuery(queryString, Object[].class)
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: y como puedo sacar esas fechas del object?

Comment: la lista de objetos la igualo a mi query?, no entiendo esa parte, o en lugar de mi lista listRegistroAcceso  que es de tipo RegistroAcceso, la cambio a list Object?

Comment: Al obtener solo las fechas, ya no retorna list de RegistroAcceso, sino de arreglo de objects: `Object[]`

Comment: ya lo cambie, edite mi pregunta de como lo cambie,pase el query a una lista de tipo Object[] ,pero me arroja [Ljava.lang.Object

Comment: Y cual es la query que estas usando? La que puse en la respuesta?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta, le pase mi find,pero no se a que te refieres con = em.createQuery(queryString, Object[].class)
    getResultList();  no entiendo esa parte

Comment: yo como implemento eso?

Comment: Tenia un error tipográfico, me faltaba un punto para la llamada del método

Comment: osea es correcto como lo tengo? solo le pongo el .getResultList()?

Comment: que va en esta parte, em.createQuery(queryString, Object[].class) ??

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75050/discussion-between-root93-and-klaimmore).

Comment: asi tengo el código intentando implementar como tu ejemplo de la otra ves